# Create a List of given Numbers in Python

Tags: python, arrays, jupyter-notebook

I would like to create an array of Integers like this (15,0,15,47,0,15,15,0,0,15,0,0,17,0,14,0,0,15,0,0,22,29,0,0,29,22,15,15,0,15,15,0,16,0,0,16,0,0,0,0,17,0,0,19,21,0,17,16,15,0,16,0,0,15,0,16,0,0,0,15,0,16,16,0,0,0,14,21,14,21,14,0,14,29,0,14,15,15,16,0,0,0,29,22,0,0,0,0,14,0,0,0,15,0,15,16,0,0,31,14,0,0,0,0,13,13,0,0,0,14,20,27,0,0,0,0,0,15,29,15,0,0,0,0,21,28,0,15,15,16,0,0,0,0,0,15,0,0,0,15,0,15,0,0,0,17,0,0,0,0,18,0,0,15,0,0,0,15,15,0,0,15,15,0,0,0,30,16,0,0,14,27,14,0,0,14,14,14,14,21,14,29,0,0,0,14,14,0,0,45,16,0,0,29,15,0,0,0,0,15,0,17,0,0,13,13,0,13,27,28,0,13,0,13,13,40,0,0,13,0,0,0,26,13,0,19,25,13,12,25,31,0,13,13,0,0,13,14,13,0,13,0,0,0,12,19,13,26,0,13,13,0,27,15,14,0,13,0,50,13,100) in Python....

I tried this:

```
data = int(x,x,x,x,x,...etc)
```

i have this error:
TypeError: int() takes at most 2 arguments (254 given)

How is it possible? I'm working on Jupyter with Python 3.7

thank you in advance!

Comment: use the list operator `[]`, `[5,0,15,47,0,15,15,0,0,15,0,0,17,0,14,0,0,15,0,0,22,29,0,0,2...]`

Comment: Ok I tried also this but when later I have to modify data in this way: Data = [[[(data+j)/100] for data in range(5)]for j in data]          I got this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int' .... How i can get a list of integers that can be modify in a second step?  Sorry I know that my explanation is not so good

Comment: Probably best if you acquaint yourself with some basic understanding of [`lists`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) (and probably the rest of the introductory tutorial) before you proceed further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you have in your question it is already a tuple, you can get a list using the list class for that effect.

```
>>> tuple_numbers = (2,3,4,5,6)
>>> list_numbers = list(tuple_numbers)
>>> list_numbers
[2,3,4,5,6]
```

I see you're new to Python, at least seems to be that way. So I'll recommend reading about [list and tuples](https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/).

If you want to apply some transformation to list items, try [map](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html).

**Note**

> Take into account that it is not the same: `list(2,3,4,5)` that `list((2,3,4,5))`. The first is wrong since you are passing more than one argument

Happy coding!

Comment: I did it but this is the error:       TypeError: list() takes at most 1 argument (254 given)

Comment: That's because you pass only one element to `list`. Take into account that it is not the same: `list(2,3,4,5)` that `list((2,3,4,5))`.  The first is wrong since you are passing more than one argument.

Comment: Use list((254integers)) instead using list (254 integers)

Answer (score 0):

If you enter help(int) on the Python interpreter:

```
>>> help(int)
```

you'll see it's documentation and a portion of it says:

*Convert a number or string to an integer ...*

Your question is not clear about where you are getting the numbers from. If you are getting them from a file, you'll have to:

1. open the file
2. read individual numbers. They will be strings.
3. apply int() to each number string
4. append the number to a list